# Query with '-' returns incorrect results in ElasticSearch NEST 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Here is the query I use to search:

```
 var response = await client.SearchAsync<MenuForElasticSearch>(searchDescriptor => searchDescriptor
                .Query(queryContainerDescriptor => queryContainerDescriptor
                    .Bool(queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor
                        .Should(queryStringQuery => queryStringQuery.Match(match => match.Field(fld => fld.DisplayName).Query(query)),
                        queryStringQuery => queryStringQuery.Wildcard(wildcard => wildcard.Field(flds => flds.DisplayName).Value($"*{query}*")),
                        queryStringQuery => queryStringQuery.Fuzzy(fuzzy => fuzzy.Field(flds => flds.DisplayName).Value(query)))
                        )));
```

There are three documents with displayName = NPW-711, NPW-677 and NPW-777. When I search NPW-711 it returns all three documents. 
Can adding `DefaultOperator(Elasticsearch.Net.DefaultOperator.And)` help? If yes, where it fits?

Comment: You would like to return only NPW-711?

Comment: yes. If I search NPW, then all three. In case I type whole word NPW-711, it should return only 1 record.

Answer (score 2):

[Match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) with AND operator will give you what you are looking for

```
var results = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("name")
            .Query(query)
            .Operator(Operator.And))));
```

output:

```
Results for query "NPW-777": NPW-777
Results for query "NPW": NPW-711,NPW-677,NPW-777
Results for query "677": NPW-677
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here is the final query:
{
"query":
{"bool":
{"should":[
  {"match":{"displayName":{"fuzziness":"AUTO","operator":"and","query":"men"}}},
  {"wildcard":{"displayName":{"value":"*men*"}}},
  {"fuzzy":{"displayName":{"value":"men"}}}
  ]
}
}
}
there is a record with displayName = 'Menu Admin'. The above query searches fine with word "menu a" but not with "menu ad". Is it due to And operator?